# How to backup and restore Windows Server 2003 DNS?

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-name-system

I'm about to do DNS replication from one site to another and just as a precaution what should I backup in case the replication goes wrong and how to restore it.

Is there a fast and easy way to backup our primary DNS server on Windows Server 2003?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sysadmin1138 is correct if it's domain-integrated. If not, you will need to look into exporting and re-importing the records. Look [here](http://www.windowsreference.com/windows-server-2008/how-to-export-dns-server-records-to-a-textcsv-file-in-windows-server-200820032000/) for an example command to do this.

Comment: Yes, that's just what I need, thanks guys for all of your response.

Answer (score 4):

If its domain-integrated, it's part of the domain and generally doesn't need backing up. AD's replica sync process should handle any problems there. If you do run into problems, your Domain as a whole is probably screwed as well and you have bigger problems.

File backed I'm not so sure of, though the DNS replication process should be robust enough that all you have to do is nuke the secondary and retransfer from Primary to get back online. If you're paranoid, backup the zone-files before doing the replication. Restoring is as simple as shutting off the DNS service, restoring the files, and firing it back up.

Comment: thanks for the comments mate, but how do I backup ? is it exporting the DNS list into TXT file or do the NTBackup then select system state ?

Comment: @Albert If it is file-backed, then yes the files are kept in text files. I don't remember the exact location, but it's buried in C:\Windows\System32\ somewhere. The files are BIND-compatible, as it happens.